# How to prevent skipping ads on iPhone ios video player?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios9, video.js, imasdk

I'm developing HTML5 video player to support HLS and play ads using IMA SDK the issue that when playing on iPhone i can easily skip the ads using the next track button on the ios player.

Any idea how to prevent that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of July 2016, the latest release of IMA3 SDK actually does prevent user from skipping ad with the next track button. To be exact, the user can still click the button, but SDK will programatically revert the playhead to the last position before the clicking.

If you are interested to know how it actually works, see my comment at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38578823/825860